# Replacing a string between strings multiple times

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace a string between strings, and it to happen multiple times.

Currently, my code is

```
var str = `**Bolded text**`
var re = new RegExp(/\*\*(.*)\*\*/gi)
let newStr = str.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>")
console.log(newStr);
```

That example works fine and returns this:

```
<b>Bolded text</b>
```

However, if I try adding multiple **texts** in the string, it does it incorrect

```
var str = `**Bolded text 1** **Bolded text 2**`
```

It returns

```
<b>Bolded text 1** **Bolded text 2</b>
```

And I want it to return

```
<b>Bolded text 1</b> <b>Bolded text 2</b>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex greedy problem, you need to add the question mark here `/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/gi`

https://regex101.com/r/c8bwEg/1

*Greedy will consume as much as possible.*

```js
var str = `**Bolded text 1** **Bolded text 2**`
var re = new RegExp(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/gi)
let newStr = str.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>")
console.log(newStr);
```